# Does MongoDB's $in clause has any max limit in number of arguments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

When using MongoDB's $in clause with Aggregate , Does That has any max limit in number of arguments ?

for example

```
Model.aggregate(
        [
            { $match : 
                { '_Id' : 
                            {
                                $in : ids
                            }
                }
            } ,
            { $group : 
                {   _id : '$roomId' ,
                    maxdate: { $max: "$date"},
                }
            },
            {$sort: { maxdate: -1} },
            {$skip: skip},
            {$limit: limitNum }
        ]
```

In ids array , how many ids i can pass ?

Currently i am not facing any issue with **ids** length till **50,000** ... but for safe side wanted to know the max limit.

I have tried to search on Mongo doc , but didnt find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of arguments in the `$in` clause itself, however, the total query size is limited to 16MB as a query is just a BSON document. Depending on the type used for `ids` (see the BSON [specification](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)), you may start running into problems when your ids length is in the order of a few millions.

Comment: what problems we run into if the ids length is in order of millions... since ur comment is 5 years old now.. is that fixed in mongodb.

Comment: It is still.the case: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to have only 10s of values in $in clause.

> It is recommended that you limit the number of parameters passed to the $in operator to tens of values. Using hundreds of parameters or more can negatively impact query performance.

refer: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/query/in/