# Is there a max limit to the $nin operator in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

My sample use case is to Query data about people who have not blocked the user
and there is no limit to the number of people that can block the user

So my query looks something like

```
db.collection().find( { followedPersonId: { $nin: [ blockerId1, blockerId2, blockerId3.....] } } )
```

So the number of Array items in the $nin operator can grow to a potentially large number, So is there a limit to the size of this array in MongoDB?

Comment: Even if there isn’t, those ids all need to be sent in the query, making the query itself huge and slow. Perhaps an in-database `$lookup` would be better?

Comment: There is a similar question for `$in` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601048/does-mongodbs-in-clause-has-any-max-limit-in-number-of-arguments `$nin` is a combination of `$in` and `$not` operators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does MongoDB's $in clause has any max limit in number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601048/does-mongodbs-in-clause-has-any-max-limit-in-number-of-arguments)

Comment: Yes it does @D.SM, thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command size limit is currently set at 48 MB. If your query is bigger than that the driver should fail when trying to serialize it, and the server should fail if it was asked to parse it.

Since your query is technically a *query document*, I imagine the lower 16 MB BSON document size limit would also apply to it. The 48 MB limit applies to find-and-modify queries that specify a query document and an update document.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is NO!

When you try to do this the query will become huge. And performance will be less.

Will the ids be in crores?
If yes then I will suggest not to go with this method.