# How to extract the field that is not equal to a set of values in Mongodb Mongoose Nodejs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am extracting the document where its `status` is not equal to Finished, the below code works well.

```js
const x = await rmm.Events.find(
    { status: { $ne: "Finished" } },
    { startTime: true, name: true, _id: false }
  );
```

However, if I want to extract the status is not equal to Finished or Voided, the below code failed.

```js
const x = await rmm.Events.find(
    { status: { $ne: ["Finished", "Voided"] } },
    { startTime: true, name: true, _id: false }
  );
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use [`$nin`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) instead

```
const x = await rmm.Events.find(
    { status: { $nin: ["Finished", "Voided"] } },
    { startTime: true, name: true, _id: false }
  );
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l_dW6gwGE7I)

Comment: It is suitable if I wan to filter `$nin: filterArray` where `filterArray.length` larger than 500? Regarding to the efficiency

Comment: yeah thats a huge filter and can affect performance see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601048/does-mongodbs-in-clause-has-any-max-limit-in-number-of-arguments?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114072/is-there-a-max-limit-to-the-nin-operator-in-mongodb) and also the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#:~:text=It%20is%20recommended%20that%20you,can%20negatively%20impact%20query%20performance.) recommend to not have hundreds